# Writing JSON array to html page with javascript after getting it from PHP query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a MySQL query that I pass to a PHP array. The PHP array is turned into a JSON array using `json_encode`. I am trying to then get this to print onto my html page. Here is what I have so far.

```
<?php
class db {
  public $conn;

  function dbLogin() {
    $this->conn = new mysqli("1.2.3.4","user","pwd","db");  
  }

  public function selectQuery() {
    $this->dbLogin();
    $query = "
        SELECT      *
        FROM        tekken_7_frame_data
    ";
    echo "<pre>";
    $resultArray = Array();
    if ($result = $this->conn->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $resultArray[] = $row;
        }

    }

    echo "</pre>";
    $resultJson = json_encode($resultArray);
  }
}

$fData = new db();
$fData->selectQuery();
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var jsonArray = <?php echo $resultJson ?>;
  document.write(jsonArray);
  for (i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
    document.write(jsonArray[i][1]);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've read up on other similar questions on StackOverflow with no luck; my html page is completely blank. I've tried placing `json_econde(...)` inside of the javascript variable `jsonArray` instead of in my PHP class. That didn't work either. I have also `var_dump`'d the PHP array with no issue (the whole thing displayed on the page), as well as placed the array in a PHP variable using `json_encode`, then echoed that array with no issue.

I have no idea how to access this JSON array. I ultimately want it in a table, but because this is my first time bridging the gap between PHP and Javascript, I figured that I would take it one step at a time so that I know exactly what is going on.

Comment: Have you tried just echoing the php variable directly to isolate the problem? Ie is the problem the PHP, or the JS? Have you viewed the page source? Check the console to make sure JS is running happily?

Comment: Yea, I should have added that. I have `var_dump`'d the PHP array with no problem. I have placed the PHP array into a variable using `json_encode`, then printed that variable with no problem either. Both arrays display on the page in full. No errors in the console when I display both arrays either.

Comment: Also, code is a bit odd. You should either return a value, or echo in the function. The problem may be that `$resultJson` variable that appears within the function, and then over in the JS part, also. I'd recommend you edit your function to NOT echo a `<pre>`, and to return the array. And then you'll have something like `$result = $db->selectQuery();`, and then `echo $result;`.

Comment: If the `jsonArray` is being displayed on the page in full, how is the page blank?

Comment: YOu have a typo in the `for` loop. It should be `i < jsonArray.length`, not `i > jsonArray.length`. This is causing the loop to end immediately without printing anything.

Comment: Haha Barmar may have spotted the problem. Also, critiquing the DB class: should have initial capital for the class name,  the field should be private, and the connection should be established in the constructor rather than for every query you make :) And I think there's a fetch_all or similar method that returns the results as an array in the first place!

Comment: I appreciate the critique, @Luke . I'm currently making the jump from procedural to object-oriented, so any feedback is definitely welcomed.

What do you mean specifically by "the field should be private"?

Comment: So public and private are called access modifiers; they're special keywords that denote where that property can be accessed from. So a private field can only be used within the declaring class, whereas a public field can be used by any class. If you make your $db field private, then only the DB class can use it, and any others (such as a hypothetical View class) won't be able to access that field. General pattern of encapsulation is to make fields private, and expose public methods.

Comment: Fields as in the properties/variables inside of the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change your function (don't use `echo`! but `return` something) to:

```
public function selectQuery() {
    $this->dbLogin();
    $query = "
        SELECT      *
        FROM        tekken_7_frame_data
    ";
    $resultArray = Array();
    if ($result = $this->conn->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $resultArray[] = $row;
        }

    }

   return json_encode($resultArray);
  }
```

and downthere:

```
$fData = new db();
$resultJson = $fData->selectQuery();
```

Comment: This answer was soooooo solid. This is exactly what I needed. Is this usually how PHP arrays are passed to Javascript via JSON?

Comment: there are many ways to do the same thing, I just fixed your code according to your logic I've seen in your post :-)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to get data from PHP into JavaScript is to use an asynchronous request (that is, "AJAX").

A javascript library greatly simplifies this process. Here's a rough example using AngularJS (http://angularjs.org).

json.php

```
// this file JUST needs to print JSON as string.
<?php
class db {
  public $conn;

  function dbLogin() {
    $this->conn = new mysqli("1.2.3.4","user","pwd","db");  
  }

  public function selectQuery() {
    $this->dbLogin();
    $query = "
        SELECT      *
        FROM        tekken_7_frame_data
    ";
    $resultArray = Array();
    if ($result = $this->conn->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $resultArray[] = $row;
        }

    }    
    return json_encode($resultArray);
  }
}

$fData = new db();
print $fData->selectQuery();
?>
```

myscript.js

```
// this will fetch your JSON string from the PHP file and 
// set $scope.myData to a JS object.
// it sets $scope.myDataString to a JSON stringified format.

angular.module('myApp' [])
  .controller('myController', function($http, $scope) {
    var $scope.myData = {};
    var $scope.myDataString = '';
    function getMyData () {
      $http.get('/json.php')
      .success( function (data) {
        $scope.myData = data;
        $scope.myDataString = JSON.stringify(data);
      })
      .error(function (err) {
         $scope.myData = {error: err};
         $scope.myDataString = "ERROR: "+JSON.stringify(data);
      })
    }
    getMyData();
  }
```

mypage.html

```
<!-- include angular and your app's file. 
     make sure to link in your app and controller -->
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src='myscript.js'>
</head>
<body ng-app='myApp'>
  <main ng-controller='myController as myCtrl'>
    <div id='myOutput'>{{myDataString}}</div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer. Thanks for putting the time in to write this up. I'm going to come back to this in a week or so once I get a little more comfortable with dealing with JSON arrays. My next task in line after this was applying some AJAX anyway, so I'll be sure to use this answer.

I'm still a little ways off in terms of applying Angular, but if the learning curve is not too bad then I'll apply your post as well.